# replace different parts of string with php

Tags: php

I have a bit of php code that posts the value of a form field like this:

```
str_replace("www.", "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])
```

This php code excludes the www part if the user entered it. I would like to exclude http and https aswell if this is entered as a value.

I tried doing something like this, but it didn't work:

```
str_replace("www."&&"http://", "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])
```

any ideas on how to exlude multiple parts

Comment: use an array: `str_replace(array('val1', 'val2'), '', $str)` read [the documentation](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$strToRemove= array("www","http","blabla");
$newStr = str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12']);
```

you put them in an array and then fed it to the `str_replace` function's first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
str_replace(array("www","http://","https://"), '', $_POST['billing_myfield12']);
```

Or, in modern PHP (anything from 5.4 onwards), the slighty less wordy:

```
str_replace(["www","http://","https://"], '', $_POST['billing_myfield12']);
```